# If else in Promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback, promise, bluebird

I try to refacter code from using callback to Promise but I got some weird behavior from Promise(bluebird)

here is the main logic

```
function func1(callback) {
  func2()
  .then(function(resultFromFunc2) {
    if (resultFromFunc2 === true) {
      callback(null, resultFromFunc2)
    } else {
      return func3()
    }
  })
  .then(function(resultFromFunc3) {
    console.log('Func 3', resultFromFunc3)
    callback(null, resultFromFunc3)
  })
  .catch(function(err) {
    console.log('error', err)
  })
}

func1(function(err, result) {
  console.log('func1', err, result);
})
```

and in `func2` and `func3` is just a simple resolve

```
function func2() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    resolve(true)
  });
}

function func3() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    resolve(true)
  });
}
```

If `func2` resolve `true` code should stop running in the first then, but I found the second then is called

here is result from terminal.

```
func1 null true
Func 3 undefined
func1 null undefined
```

How could I stop calling the second then when `func2` is resolve `true`

Comment: @JaromandaX sorry, I don't understand what you mean

Comment: your code is still using a callback - what is the original code you are trying to refactor?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? What should be called?

Comment: @paqash I would like to check if result from `func2` is true `then` callback, else just call `func3`

Answer (score 1):

@Phattahana,
Just posting my thoughts on your question.

As you have said in your answer, you shouldn't be calling `callback()` from the 1st then. Or else you should be ready to change the workflow and remove the `2nd then`. there are lot many possibilities.

In a specific scenario, where you want the code to be executed just like the question you posted (ie; if the `if condition` is true, donot call 2nd then - scenario), you can have your code like below.

```
var Promise = require("bluebird");
function func1(callback) {
  func2()
    .then((resultFromFunc2) => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          if (resultFromFunc2 === true) {
            callback(null, resultFromFunc2);
          } else {
            resolve(func3());
          }
        });
    }).then((resultFromFunc3) => {
      console.log('Func 3', resultFromFunc3)
      callback(null, resultFromFunc3)
    }).catch((err) => {
      console.log('error', err)
    });
}

func1((err, result) => {
  console.log('func1', err, result);
  return 1;
});

function func2() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    resolve(false)
  });
}

function func3() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    resolve(true)
  });
}
```

The code inside the `1st then` should be made into a separate promise resolving function and should be resolving it only if the condition is not met.

Hope its clear.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is with your second `then` section. If you remove it, everything should work as expected (if I understand correctly). See the snippet below - if you change `func2` to resolve(false), `func3` will be called, otherwise the callback will be called.

```js
function func1(callback) {
  func2()
  .then(function(resultFromFunc2) {
    if (resultFromFunc2 === true) {
      callback(null, resultFromFunc2)
    } else {
      return func3()
    }
  })
  .catch(function(err) {
    console.log('error', err)
  })
}

func1(function(err, result) {
  console.log('func1', err, result);
})

function func2() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  console.log('func2');
  resolve(true)
  });
}

function func3() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  console.log('func3')
resolve(true)
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just found the solution,

```
function func1(callback) {
  func2()
  .then(function(resultFromFunc2) {
    if (resultFromFunc2 === true) {
      return 'result from func2'
    } else {
      return func3()
    }
  })
  .then(function(result) {
    callback(null, result)
  })
  .catch(function(err) {
    console.log('error', err)
  })
}
```

I should not callback in the first then because whatever return from first then it send to the second then.

I miss understand behavior of Promise. first I think it will not call the second then if the first then doesn't return Promise.

Comment: `I try to refacter code from using callback to Promise` - that's still using a callback

Comment: @JaromandaX I could not refacter all function at the same time so I need to refacter from inner function first so the others parts should not effect.